# Gradio UI is not displaying/working properly, how to fix that?

Tags: gradio, llamacpp, privategpt

I did follow these instructions to install privateGPT:

```
git clone https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT.git 

conda create -n privategpt python=3.11

conda activate privategpt

#loading modules

module load  Anaconda3

module load CUDA/12.2.2

#install poetry 

pip install poetry

# Install dependencies
poetry install --with ui,local

# Download Embedding and LLM models. all customization can be done in setup

#used this model: mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q6_K.gguf

poetry run python scripts/setup

CMAKE_ARGS='-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on' poetry run pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir llama-cpp-python

PGPT_PROFILES=local make run
```

I run this on: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB

When I run the above I am not getting any error but gradio UI doesn’t pop up for me, I am only stuck here:

```
15:31:43.420 [INFO    ] llama_index.indices.loading - Loading all indices.
15:31:43.567 [INFO    ]         private_gpt.ui.ui - Mounting the gradio UI, at path=/
15:31:43.618 [INFO    ]             uvicorn.error - Started server process [1909083]
15:31:43.618 [INFO    ]             uvicorn.error - Waiting for application startup.
15:31:43.618 [INFO    ]             uvicorn.error - Application startup complete.
15:31:43.619 [INFO    ]             uvicorn.error - Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Can you please let me know why is this happening and how can I resolve it?